# Change background an object shape using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to implement a clothing design website, but I'm encountering a problem.

I have 1 image shirt, 1 image cloth. I draw shirt to canvas. Now, I want to change cloth shirt by image cloth. But I do not know how to do it.

Example: http://sbhvietnam.vn/shirt-by-hand.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use composite modes to achieve this. Provided the images are loaded and the *background behind the image is transparent*, and you have set up canvas and context (here `ctx`) you could do something like this:

```
/// clear if you reuse this method to avoid pixelated outline
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

/// draw shirt shape
ctx.drawImage(imgShirt, 0, 0);

/// change composite mode for next draw
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';  /// source-in is an option

/// draw cloth image on top and it will take the shape of the shirt image.
ctx.drawImage(imgCloth, 0, 0);

/// reset composite mode to default mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

Notice that if you should choose to use `source-in` instead of `source-atop` you will have to redraw `imgShirt` every time you want to change the image on top of it.

You can wrap it up in a function you call each time you need to redraw the cloth.

Comment: Thank @Ken Fyrstenberg, I using image.onload + your way, it working. but i can't blend color. Example: ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';. Why why it happened? Thank you